# JTabbedPane repaint does not work

Tags: java, swing, jtabbedpane

This is not a repeat question. Yes there are similar, but none have provided a working answer.

```
public class Tool extends JPanel implements ActionListener{

public JPanel Panel;

public Tool() {

}

public void show(){
    displayStuff();

          Panel.setVisible(true);
          revalidate();
          repaint();
    }
}

Tool MyTool = new Tool();
JPanel Master = new JPanel();
JPanel Dash = = new JPanel();
JTabbedPane Tabs = new JTabbedPane();
JTabbedPane Tabs.addTab("Dash", Dash);
JTabbedPane Tabs.addTab("Tool", MyTool.Panel);
Master.add(Tabs);
```

The real code is much more complex. But the basic issue is that when changes occurs on MyTool.Panel as a result of user pressing some buttons.

MyTool.Panel does NOT get repainted until I use mouse to move Master.

How can I force it to repaint?

Comment: There is not enough code here to provide an answer.  I suspect the problem is in the paintComponent methods of your panels.  I can say for certain that standard Swing components in a JTabbedPane always repaint properly when the user switches tabs.  You may want to run the SwingSet2 demo to see for yourself (plus, it comes with its source code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not a perfect solution but you can validate and redraw the entire application, thats what I have done in the past. I've used something like

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel{
     public void doRedraw(){
         getTopLevelAncestor().revalidate();
         getTopLevelAncestor().repaint();
     }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: try {
   getTopLevelAncestor().revalidate();
  } catch (Exception e) {
   // TODO: handle exception
   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"error: "+e);
  }    I get a null pointer error here?

Comment: I think while your creating your panel you can get a null pointer for the top level ancestor. just add an if(getTopLevelAncestor() != null) into the code